Generating function for A261041

Let $a(n)$ be A261041 (i.e., number of partitions of subsets of $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$, where consecutive integers are required to be in different parts).
Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence with generating function $B(x)$ such that
$$
B(x) = (1+x)\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{\prod\limits_{j=0}^{i} (1-jx-x^2)}.
$$

I conjecture that
$$
b(n)=a(n).
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to compute $b(n)$:
upto1(n) = Vec((1+x)*sum(i=0, n, x^i/prod(j=0, i, 1-j*x-x^2)) + x*O(x^n))
upto2(n) = my(v1, v2, v3, v4); v1 = vector(2*n-1, i, 1); v2 = vector(2*n-1, i, 0); v3 = vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1] = 1; v3[2] = 2; for(i=1, n-1, v4 = v1; for(j=1, 2*(n-i)-1, v1[j] = j*v1[j] + v2[j] + v1[j+1]); v3[i+2] = v3[i+1] + v1[1]; v2 = v4); v3

Is there a way to prove it?

A simpler expression for $B(x)$ in terms of Bell numbers: $$B(x) = \frac1{1-x} \sum_{k\geq0} B_k\cdot\big(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\big)^k.$$

Let us derive a formula for $a(n)$.
We will employ the inclusion-exclusion principle to get $a(n)$ as the number of partitions not satisfying any of the properties $P_i =$ "elements $i$ and $i+1$ get into the same part", $i\in[n-1]$.
Any collection of properties describe some maximal chains of consecutive elements going into the same parts. For example, $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_4$ together describe chains $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5)$, from which the elements should go into the same parts to satisfy those properties.
It is convenient to describe those maximal chains as a nonnegative composition $(k_0,l_1,k_1,\dots,l_c,k_c)$ of $n$, where the numbers $k_0\geq 0, l_1\geq2, k_1\geq0, \dots, l_c\geq2, k_c\geq0$ are the lengths of the consecutive chains forming $1,2,\dots,n$ such that those of lengths $l_1, \dots, l_c$ are resulted from the properties. In the above example with $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_4$ and, say, $n=6$ we have the composition $(0,3,0,2,1)$.
Clearly, $s:=(k_0,l_1,k_1,\dots,l_c,k_c)$ corresponds to a collection of $l_1-1 + \dots +l_c-1 = L-c$ properties, where $L:=l_1+\dots+l_c$. Also, the number of partitions of subsets of $[n]$ satisfying $s$ equals
$$\sum_{m=L}^n \binom{n-L}{m-L} B_{m-L+c},$$
where $m$ corresponds to the subset sizes and $B_{m-L+c}$ is Bell number.
Hence, by inclusion-exclusion we have
\begin{split}
a(n) &= \sum_{L=0}^n \sum_{c=0}^{[L/2]} \binom{n-L+c}{c} \binom{L-c-1}{L-2c} (-1)^{L-c} \sum_{m=L}^n \binom{n-L}{m-L} B_{m-L+c} \\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} B_k \sum_{c\geq 0} \sum_{L\geq 2c} \binom{n-L+c}{c} \binom{L-c-1}{L-2c} (-1)^{L-c} \binom{n-L}{k-c} \\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} B_k \sum_{c\geq 0} \binom{k}c \sum_{L\geq 2c} \binom{n-L+c}{k} \binom{L-c-1}{L-2c} (-1)^{L-c} \\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} B_k \sum_{c\geq 0} \binom{k}c (-1)^{n+k} [x^{n-k}] x^c (1+x)^{-k-1} (1-x)^{-c} \\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} B_k (-1)^{n+k} [x^{n-k}] (1+x)^{-k-1} \big(1+\frac{x}{1-x})^k \\
&=[x^n] \frac1{1-x} \sum_{k\geq 0} B_k \big(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\big)^k,
\end{split}
which matches the expression for $B(x)$ I gave in the comments.

Thank you for answer! Could you add a proof of the equivalence of the two expressions for $B(x)$?

That's almost trivial by recognizing the generating function for Stirling numbers of second kind in your expression for $B(x)$.

The OEIS entry should probably point to this MO answer, rather than to Max Alekseyev's user page.

@TimothyChow: It does point to this page in the Links section, so I'm not sure what is your concern.

@MaxAlekseyev Ah, I missed that...sorry.

@TimothyChow: No problem! Thanks for checking up the OEIS sequence.
